# Drools comparing objects in working memory

Tags: drools

I am trying to accumulate similar objects in working memory and set actions based on object attributes. My Rule: 3 or more procedures done on the same date for a patient by the same provider. Condition: Same date of service and same provider ID Action: 100% for 1st procedure, 50% for 2nd procedure and 25% for remaining. Each line item contains details about the procedure.

My Model object:

```
public class LineItem  {

  private Date dateOfService;
  private String procedureCode;
  private String providerID;
  private double billedAmount;
  private double allowableAmount;

  //getters and setters
}
```

Drools Rule:

```
**rule "Multiple Procedures done on the same day by Same Provider"**
lock-on-active true
when
    $lineItem1 : LineLevelData ( $dateOfService : dateOfService , $providerId : providerId, reasonCode == null, $lineNumber : lineNumber ) 
    and
    $lineItem2 : LineLevelData ( lineNumber!= $lineNumber , dateOfService == $dateOfService , providerId == $providerId, reasonCode == null ) 
    and
    accumulate( $lineItem: LineLevelData( dateOfService == $dateOfService , providerId == $providerId, reasonCode == null );
    $list: collectList( $lineItem ) ) 

then 

    System.out.println("List size: " + $list.size () );
    for ( int i = 0; i < $list.size(); i++ ){
        LineLevelData lineItem = (LineLevelData)$list.get(i);
        if(i == 0){
            modify(lineItem){ setReimbursementAmount(0.8* ( lineItem.getBilledAmount() ) ) 
            };
            System.out.println("Line Number: " + lineItem.getLineNumber() );
        }       
        else if(i == 1){
            modify(lineItem) {  setReimbursementAmount(0.5* (lineItem.getBilledAmount() ) ) 
            };
            System.out.println("Line Number: " + lineItem.getLineNumber() );
        }

        else {
            modify(lineItem ){ setReimbursementAmount(0.25* (lineItem.getBilledAmount() ) ) 
            };
            System.out.println("Line Number: " + lineItem.getLineNumber() );
        }
    }
```

Java code:

```
LineLevelData line1Item = new LineLevelData();
line1Item.setLineNumber(1);
line1Item.setProcedureCode("99201");
line1Item.setDateOfService(new GregorianCalendar(2017, 9, 15).getTime());
line1Item.setBilledAmount(1000);
line1Item.setProviderId("670112");
billLineItems.add(line1Item);

LineLevelData line2Item = new LineLevelData();
line2Item.setLineNumber(2);
line2Item.setProcedureCode("99205");
**line2Item.setDateOfService(new GregorianCalendar(2017, 8, 20).getTime());
line2Item.setProviderId("670118");**
line2Item.setBilledAmount(1500);

billLineItems.add(line2Item);

LineLevelData line3Item = new LineLevelData();
line3Item.setLineNumber(3);
line3Item.setProcedureCode("99049");
**line3Item.setDateOfService(new GregorianCalendar(2017, 8, 20).getTime());
line3Item.setProviderId("670118");**
line3Item.setBilledAmount(1000);
billLineItems.add(line3Item);

LineLevelData line4Item = new LineLevelData();
line4Item.setLineNumber(4);
line4Item.setProcedureCode("99058");
**line4Item.setDateOfService(new GregorianCalendar(2017, 8, 20).getTime());**
line4Item.setBilledAmount(520);
**line4Item.setProviderId("670118");**
billLineItems.add(line4Item);


//Inserting facts in working memory
for(LineLevelData billLineItem : buildBillLineItems()){
    kSession.insert(billLineItem);
    log.info("Inserted Line Item : " + billLineItem.getLineNumber());
            }
int rulesFired =  kSession.fireAllRules(new RuleNameEqualsAgendaFilter("Multiple Procedures done on the same day by Same Provider"));
```

According to my test above line items with line number 2 , 3 and 4 should be updated. Instead I am getting line number 1, 3 and 4.

Rule Output:

```
List size: 3
Line Number: 4
Line Number: 3
Line Number: 1
Multiple Procedures rule is fired...Wed Sep 20 00:00:00 CDT 2017
===========Rule Fired============ : MULTIPLE PROCEDURES DONE ON THE SAME DAY BY SAME PROVIDER
No. of Rules fired: 1

 Line Item Number: 1
 Billed amount: 1500.0
 Reimbursable amount: 375.0
 Reason Code: CHI
 Message: Coverage for all subsequent procedures is 25%
 Line Item Number: 4
 Billed amount: 520.0
 Reimbursable amount: 416.0
 Reason Code: NR
 Message: Submit to Nurse Review. 100% of UCR at 80th percentile. 
 Line Item Number: 3
 Billed amount: 1000.0
 Reimbursable amount: 500.0
 Reason Code: PHY
 Message: Manual review is required. 50% coverage for secondary procedure. 
 **Line Item Number: 2
 Billed amount: 1000.0
 Reimbursable amount: 0.0
 Reason Code: null
 Message: null**
```

Comment: Line #4 shouldn't be updated either, because it has a different date than the other 2, right?
Could you print in the RHS of your rule the values for `$lineItem1` and `$lineItem2`?

Comment: Hi Esteban, Thanks for responding. There is a typo for Date of service in Line number 2 and 3 which should be Sep 20, 2017. There is no RHS for $lineItem1 and $lineItem2. Those are used for comparing the objects in working memory and then accumulate the matching objects with same date of service and provider ID. There should be a better way to achieve this rules. Appreciate if you can suggest the optimal way of re-writing this rule. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Esteban - I found out the issue why the line numbers getting changed. It is sorted based on the procedure amount in the service side. Rule is now working fine but instead of using loop in the RHS side, is there a better way to achieve this.